# How to lazy initialize a map using std::optional, and add to it using emplace

Tags: c++, c++17, lazy-initialization

I have a class with a std::optional map, the reasoning here is that a map is expensive to construct so I'm looking for ways to minimize the impact.  As the map is not always used, the thinking is why construct it until it IS used.

I'm having trouble with adding values to the class after construction, the syntax eludes me :), or perhaps I misunderstood some limitation and it can't actually be used this way.  Some insight would be appreciated.

```
class A {
public:
void addValues() {
_map_value.emplace(/* what goes here ?*/);
// It is expecting something like std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<std::map< .... initializer list
}
private:
std::optional<std::map<std::string, ResourceValue>> _map_value{};
};
```

I've tried making pair's and various forms of emplace.  I see i'm supposed to use std::optional::emplace, but I think this is just for construction, not for accessing and adding to the map afterwards.  How can I manage this map after its been optionally constructed?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and the compiler error. `Class` should be `class` and `}` should be `};` I suppose those are typos, so please show real code

Comment: btw what makes you think constructing an empty map would be expensive? I never measured it, but I would be surprised if constructing an optional map really makes a difference

Comment: For me this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I have no clue why you need lazy initialization and this knowledge is necessary to properly implement lazy initialization.

Comment: "a map is expensive to construct" citation needed. An *empty* map is quite cheap to construct. Perhaps you mean "expensive to populate"

Comment: @Caleth if you are constructing thousands of objects maps start to come out on top as quite expensive to set up.  Pretty simple to reproduce, create the class above a million times add a few bool's and int's for good measure and have a look where most of the time is spent.  It will show that initializing a map is an issue in that scenario.

Comment: @MarekR Its quite straight forward, std::optional allows me to defer creation of a map until its needed (maybe never) as I explained above.  If I misunderstood how optional works and it doesn't do that feel free to correct me.

Comment: @DavidDumke you still miss the point: doing lazy initialization inside a method named `addValues` doesn't make seance. It is violation of this pattern. Lazy initialization is performed in some getter to provide value which is heavy in calculation. It is like building long stairs to ground floor. That is why I still think your question suffers from `XY problem` (you got  answer for Y where in fact you still have a problem with X).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::optional<T>::emplace` takes a number of arguments and invokes the constructor of `T` with those arguments to construct the managed value in place. In this case it doesn't take any parameters, because you wouldn't pass any parameters to the constructor of map.

Maybe check beforehand if the optional is already initialized or not and then access the managed object with `->`:

```
if(!_map_value) {           // if the optional is empty
    _map_value.emplace();   // construct
    _map_value->insert(...); // Do stuff with the map
}
```